# Office Outlook Web Addin does not work on Office Client 2016

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an addin using Angular 5 version, I have built it and deployed on a Apache server with sercure http, I have tested this addin on Office Web App by logging in with Different users and I see that it works as I expected,

But the problem Now is I opened the Outlook Client with specific user configured with it, Addin Icon on the ribbon appears but when I click on it just shows the Empty section in Addin window at the right side.

The Icon and name of Add-In appears on the Ribbon, Even after I click the Add-In Button the Name of the Add-In appears as a header in Add-in window but rest  is blank with no error message.

Note: The Outlook Client is on another machine mut on the same domain. On this machine I tried the Add-In from browser it works fine.

Office Outlook Client Version is **"Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.4639.1000) 32bit**

Exchange server Version is **"Version 15.1(Build 1466.3)"**

In Outlook Client I also want to know that how can I debug the Addin.

Where I can see the error logs if button dont appears in the Outlook Clients its all stucked in between.

Comment: Does your add-in work in OWA in Internet Explorer? Outlook uses IE to render the add-in so if there is an unsupported feature (Promises, ES6 syntax) you will need to polyfill it to support IE.

Comment: Yes exactly i also keep an eye on it but here the addin is perfectly working on ie, as our custumers are only using IE

Comment: Did attaching the debugger help you get unblocked?

Comment: I cannot attach debugger as i said the issue is on customer  environment i cannot install visual studio or any other stuff on customers machine.

Comment: Can you ask them to update to the latest version 16.0.4735.1000 and see if they still see the issue. Could you also share the manifest so we can try it on our end for the client build number you mention

Comment: Sure i ll give a try once and will update it soon

Comment: Its actually bit unpredictable because the versions are exactly same on my environment. For both outlook client and addins but only at outlook client its not working but yes we will find it out lets see after updating it

Comment: Is that the only customer facing this issue? Are others in his org able to access the add-in?

Comment: Actually this was the first outlook client on customers side i installed addin to test with one user. I need to test with other users and clients too but i have limited access on their side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution in this case, The actual problem is Document mode of Internet Explorer.

As we know that Web Add-in uses Internet Explore Frame to load. After when I debug it Using F12 Debugger. I came to know in the Emulation section the document mode was default selected to 7. And the Document Mode 7 doesnt have latest supported JavaScript suport(My Addin is built on Angular 5 version using Routes).

So in index.html of my Add-in Project I missed to mention the document mode in Header with meta tag, that which emulation version I want to run the script with.

I have added to head of index.html in my add-in

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Now it works on my client and uses emulation Document Mode 10
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your add-in in Outlook Desktop by [attaching a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane). You may not see the affordance like in Excel, but right clicking on the taskpane will show the same control to attach the debugger in the context menu.

Comment: As I said before, This was the situation on Customer side so it is not possible to use the debugger with Visual studio, So what I have done is i used F12 Debugger for the addin which loads on Client, I got the solution I will post the same in my Own answer.