# Add-In is not loading on Outlook Desktop application on Windows

Tags: jquery, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created an addon for outlook that basically renders a web page in it.
It is working fine on web (all browsers) and outlook desktop app on mac too but it is not working on outlook desktop application for windows.

Please, find the manifest.xml below for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
<Id>faf79be0-c75f-48a4-823f-67e02ca31a86</Id>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>Sachin Goel</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="stageAddIn 1.4" />
<Description DefaultValue="Sample staging add-in  version 1.4 for integrating bot" />
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/assets/img/favicon.ico" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/assets/img/favicon.ico" />
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/" />
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>http://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
    <Host Name="Document" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
<FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin" />
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
        </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin" />
        </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
</FormSettings>
<Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
</Rule>
<DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                                <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                    <SourceLocation resid="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" />
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/assets/img/favicon.ico" />
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/assets/img/favicon.ico" />
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://leena.ai/assets/img/favicon.ico" />
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://demo-sales.chatteron.io/function-file/function-file.html" />
            <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin" />
            <bt:Url id="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://staging-web.chatteron.io/addin" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group" />
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Staging Add-In" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Staging Add-In" />
            <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Compose command" />
            <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Compose command super tip" />
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane." />
            <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Compose command super tip description." />
        </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I have tried many solutions but no luck. Could this be related to iframes as index.html renders the external web page in an iframe?

Comment: Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?

Please add in the errors you are getting and what you've tried to resolve it?

Comment: It is not showing any of kind or error on desktop application. I have tried desktop application debugging via Vorlon.js but found nothing

Comment: Then add in the details of how you know it's not working and what you've tried to do to resolve it. You will likely get more of a reply from people here if do.

Comment: There is a empty page in the addin space for desktop application.
I have tried to serve both addin-server and webpage to be rendered from same dns as earlier there was  warning on iframes regarding the different source of origin.

Comment: We are also facing similar issue with webaddin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295729/office-outlook-web-addin-does-not-work-on-office-client-2016). Outlook uses IE  to render, so this could be a compatibility issue.

Comment: @SureshGowthamS tried this but still not working.

Comment: If your addin is showing as a blank pane, it's possible that there are issues with IE rendering your addin. Have you tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10 and to reload the addin with debugger attached?  Another thing to look into: you mentioned trying all browsers with Outlook on the web, does that include Internet Explorer (and not Edge)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the add-in into the your Outlook account? In the picture I signed the button for managing add-ins.

[Here is an image that I talk about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbyrO.png)