# Office Web Addins in outlook client stucked on loading screen after installing webview2 but works perfectly fine in browser

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, webview2

we are using office365 accounts, We have office addins hosted on apache server on intranet, Some days back after windows update on customer side the addins stopped working ,it means the addins just stucks on loading page in the addin Pane, but on the same windows machine if we use browser for  the office365 addin works fine for all the mail boxes. Just some thing new happened after the update, So we decided to roll back the update on one machine, but still the same now on outlook client. This is not similar this question [stackoverflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295729/office-outlook-web-addin-does-not-work-on-office-client-2016), Please have alook at the image below

[image: stucked on loading]

To debug this issue

1. we have used F12 debugger, but unfortunately the addin frame is not getting listed in the F12 debugger.
2. we then stopped the apache server to have a look if addins says that the server or url is invalid but didnt helped still the addin looks stucked on loading page, as per our understanding the addin is even reaching the apache server, on the other hand in the browser is the server is stopped the outlook web indicates that url is not reachable,

EDIT: After uninstalling webView2 these addins started working back in outlook client.

So after this we think that is there any configuration in outlook client for addins to look for intranet urls or may be some thing blocking the outlook client to search for the url given in menifest,

Note: This addin was working fine before and stopped working after outlook and windows updated. This issue again found on customer environment and we cannot install other applications to dubug because of security concerns

Hope there would be something to debug this more.

Comment: What Outlook and Windows versions is the effected customer on (before and after update)? Just to clarify, is it all add-ins or just "test Archiver (V6)" that is stuck on the loading screen?

Comment: Is it a sample add-in? Have you tried using a newly created add-in generated by yeoman? Does it work correctly out of the box?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev have the same problem with newly created one also...

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT here in this case all the addins are behaving same as problem mentioned.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have installed Insight Addin to t he same client , It works , But the addins which are hosted on Our local apache server dont works in Outlook Client , But same works with Outlook web....

Comment: Could you try using any other web server locally? It seems the problem is in the apache web server configuration.

Comment: I dont thinks so its apache server config because it was working fine until the windows update is installed.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT is there any way to get the trace when addin loads like some log files in local machine or something we can get in written about what went wrong if addins just shows loading icon until we close it????

Comment: Collecting and analzying traces require working with Microsoft Office support and we cannot do so on stackoverflow. Here are questions that may help:
1. Windows and Outlook version is relevant because the web engine may have changed.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/announcing-webview2-for-office-add-ins-platform/  This identify the correct debugger to use.
2. Could you try a store addin addins in addition to Insights? ScriptLabs, at https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001603?src=office&tab=Overview would let us know if other more typical addin loads

Comment: Insights being pre-installed to mailboxes is slightly different from user-installed addins  3. Collecting fiddler traces can help determine if any requests are made to the web server.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Actually we have debugged it with some manual operations here, after we uninstalled Edge webView2 the addins started working back on client., But as it automacally installs with office 365 version 2101 or later. just uninstalling is not a correct way to solve this, Please suggest the steps in this case .Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you collect the ULS logs on the machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/diagnostic-logs/collect-office-diagnostic-logs